# Modify JSON output in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to remove some elements from my JSON output.

My Output is:

```
[
    {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "_id": "6580f69587f0f77a14091c22",
                "email": "janzboy@gmail.com",
                "first_name": "Janz",
                "last_name": "Boy",
                "password": "1995",
            }
        ],
        "first_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/customer?page=1"
    }
]
```

I want a simple output like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "6580f69587f0f77a14091c22",
    "email": "janzboy@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Janz",
    "last_name": "Boy",
    "password": "1995",
  }
]
```

Here's my controller:

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $customers=Customer::paginate(10);
        return response()->json([
            'data'=> $customers 
        ]);
    }
}
```

Do me your biggest favor, brother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the JSON output how you want, you should change the data you send in the response. Instead of sending the whole paginated object, you should only send the data part of it.

```php
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $customers = Customer::paginate(10);
        return response()->json($customers->items());
    }
}
```

In this code, `$customers->items()` will return an array of the current page items, giving you the desired output.

Comment: Appreciate it sir, perfectly work for me !

Comment: Can you give me documentation for this sir ? I still didn't found yet..

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired output without the pagination information, you can modify the code to return just the array of customers without using pagination:

```
 class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $customers = Customer::all(); // Retrieve all customers
        return response()->json($customers);
    }
}
```

This modification fetches all customers without pagination and directly returns the array of customer objects in the JSON response. However, keep in mind that using `Customer::all()` can be inefficient for large datasets since it retrieves all records at once. Pagination is typically used to handle large data sets more efficiently by breaking them into smaller chunks. If you have a large number of customers, it might be better to stick with pagination and refine the output format on the client-side to fit your desired structure.